# Insert Scala Enum through JOOQ

Tags: mysql, scala, enums, jooq

I've used the JOOQ generator to create a mapping of my Mysql DB schema,
it creates an enum on my enums' column, but when I try to insert the value to the DB I get an error.

This is the enum:

```
object Operationtype {

  val Read : Operationtype = enums.Read
  val Write : Operationtype = enums.Write

  def values() : Array[Operationtype] = Array(
      Read
    , Write
  )

  def valueOf(s : String) : Operationtype = s match {
    case "Read" => Read
    case "Write" => Write
    case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException()
  }
}

sealed trait Operationtype extends EnumType {
  override def getSchema : Schema = null
  override def getName : String = "Operationtype"
}

case object Read extends Operationtype {
  override def getLiteral : String = "Read"
}

case object Write extends Operationtype {
  override def getLiteral : String = "Write"
}
```

This is the column type that using the enum(i've changed the Table specific Record type to org.jooq.Record)

```
 val OPERATIONTYPE : TableField[Record, Operationtype] =
 createField("OperationType",
 org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDataType.VARCHAR.asEnumDataType(classOf[enums.Operationtype]),
 "")
```

This is the code that get me the error:

```
 DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MYSQL).insertInto(Tables.TEST,
 Test.TEST.OPERATIONTYPE)   .values(Operationtype.Read)    .execute()
```

This is the error:

> Exception in thread "main" org.jooq.exception.MappingException: Cannot
>   create instance of class enums.Read$
>       at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:787)
>       at org.jooq.impl.DSL.mostSpecific(DSL.java:15189)
>       at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:15157)
>       at org.jooq.impl.DSL.val(DSL.java:15125)
>       at org.jooq.impl.Tools.field(Tools.java:1022)
>       at org.jooq.impl.AbstractStoreQuery.addValue(AbstractStoreQuery.java:83)
>       at org.jooq.impl.InsertImpl.addValue(InsertImpl.java:295)
>       at org.jooq.impl.InsertImpl.values(InsertImpl.java:274)
>       at org.jooq.impl.InsertImpl.values(InsertImpl.java:158)
>       at org.jooq.impl.InsertImpl.values(InsertImpl.java:91)
>       at DbMain$.main(DbMain.scala:21)
>       at DbMain.main(DbMain.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
>   Caused by: org.jooq.exception.MappingException: Error while looking up
>   Scala enum
>       at org.jooq.impl.Tools.enums(Tools.java:3197)
>       at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.asEnumDataType(DefaultDataType.java:661)
>       at org.jooq.impl.DefaultDataType.getDataType(DefaultDataType.java:783)
>       ... 16 more Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Comment: See also: https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/5758